# Image Quality ML

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Is it possible to write a program that determines if an image is bad quality or not (saturation dimness etc.) More specifically, I want to compare good photos of food vs bad photos. I have a large database of good and bad photos, but very little experience with ML. Is what I'm trying to do even possible/feasible? If so, how do I start?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can create neural network which can classify the quality of images based on features like saturation, dimness, etc
by using convolutional layers and fully connected layers.

To classify images, you will need to create image dataset which is separated into labels
like saturation good images, saturation bad images, dimness good images, dimness bad images

This problem is called image classification. So you can search more about how to do this with that key word.

The way to label images is that you can create directories like this

```
train
  saturation_good_images
  saturation_bad_images
  dimness_good_images
  dimness_bad_images
test
  saturation_good_images
  saturation_bad_images
  dimness_good_images
  dimness_bad_images
```

and put proper images into each directory.

And you can easily do this labeling by using DataSet class and DataLoader class of PyTorch deep learning framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm planning to build a similar by using Keras and doing [transfer learning with a pretrained model](https://www.learnopencv.com/keras-tutorial-transfer-learning-using-pre-trained-models/). With that method you don't need as much training data as you normally would to train that deep neural network.

Before diving into neural networks it is usually a good idea to build a baseline model first. I recommend just using some basic methods from [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html).

Comment: This seems like it answers any question about deep learning. How does transfer learning help *this task*? What in scikit-learn should he use for this and why?

Comment: Well, as in any other application of transfer learning, the goal is to generate some features which are better than just using the raw pixel values. I haven't tried that so I don't know if it works for this task, but that's just what I'm planning to do.

The hyperlink to scikit-learn is a tutorial using CIFAR-10. Using the same methods as there would be the simplest image classifier I can think of, and therefore a suitable baseline model.